# Quel est la difference entre jouer au / faire du + sport?

Tags: verbes

Bonjour,

je suis en train d'apprendre le français et je voudrais savoir quand on doit utiliser :

> *faire du (de la)* + sport

et

> *jouer au (à la) + sport*

?

Comment: There is apparently no reason for the downvote. This is a fine question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans jouer au *sport* il peut y avoir un aspect ludique (divertissement amusement), par exemple, on va dire : "je vais jouer au football avec mes amis", on dira cependant : "je fais du football" pour dire que l'on en joue dans un club. 
Cependant les deux peuvent être utilisés.

Comment: Attention aussi que dans certains cas on ne joue jamais : on fait de l'escalade, de la natation, du cyclisme, de la voile, de l'athlétisme... J'aurais cependant toutes les peines du monde à en sortir une règle. Peut-être la notion de course Vs. match ? Individuel vs collectif ? (bien qu'on joue au tennis...)

Answer (score 4):

Au Québec, nous utilisons rarement `faire du soccer` ou `faire du basketball`, mais nous utilisons plutôt `jouer au soccer`, `jouer au basketball` pour tous les sports qui ne sont pas des actions. Pour le niveau professionel, nous utilisons tout de même `jouer au soccer professionnellement`.

Si toutefois le sport n'est pas un `jeu` mais plutôt une action, comme l'escale ou la nage, alors nous utilisons la forme `faire de l'escalade`.

Je dirais que `faire du soccer` ou `faire du basketball` sont des expressions qui s'entendent mais qui probablement ne s'écrivent pas.

Comment: Je pense que j'utiliserais le nom pour le professionnel si on me posait la question du genre _c'est quoi ta profession_, je dirais _joueuse de soccer_ par exemple et non que je joue professionnellement, même si c'est une bonne précision à mon avis. Mon exp. perso. c'est que je n'ai jamais entendu je crois _faire du soccer/basketball_, mais bon, tout est possible. Merci !

Comment: Je gardais le verbe afin de simplifier les notions de français pour quelqu'un qui apprend, mais je suis d'accord avec toi @floquonsd'oùpepperx